# Metric.TryGetDataSeries returning false, despite dimensions cap being respected

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, metrics

I am trying to use the Metric.TryGetDataSeries Method (documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.metric.trygetdataseries?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ApplicationInsights_Metric_TryGetDataSeries_Microsoft_ApplicationInsights_Metrics_MetricSeries__System_Boolean_System_String___) to obtain a MetricSeries which can then be used to send metrics as follows:

```
MetricSeries series;
bool canTrack = metric.TryGetDataSeries(out series, true, dimensionValuesWithCanvasId.ToArray());
if (canTrack)
{
    series.TrackValue(value);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception($"Failed to track value for metric with dimensions: {string.Join(",", this.dimensionNames)}");
}
```

However, our logging shows we are seeing exceptions consistently. Example log: *Failed to create metric DownloadReadDurationInMs with dimensions: Filename,StreamSzInKB,DataSourceId.* Screenshot of log below for good measure:

[image: Failed to create metric DownloadReadDurationInMs with dimensions: Filename,StreamSzInKB,DataSourceId.]

In other words, we are seeing TryGetDataSeries return false in some cases. Per the docs, the function returns as follows:

> True if the MetricSeries indicated by the specified dimension names
>   could be retrieved or created; False if the indicated series could not
>   be retrieved or created because createIfNotExists is false or because
>   a dimension cap or a metric series cap was reached.

Clearly createIfNotExists == true, so it must be that "a dimension cap or a metric series cap was reached". But if we look at our logs, there are 3 dimensions, so I don't think any cap is being exceeded either (though I don't know where to look to verify this - same thing with the "series cap" too).

So, questions:

1. What are the exact values of these dimensions/series caps?
2. Assuming I am not exceeding those caps (based on the logs, it seems likely that I am within the cap), is there something else that could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

I was pointed to this documentation (only added 3 weeks ago!) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/get-metric#dimension-and-time-series-capping which details information regarding the dimensions and series caps.

Per the docs:

> The default limits are no more than 1000 total data series per metric,
>   and no more than 100 different values per dimension.

I was surprised by the "unique value" cap, and so it seems likely that I am actually exceeding this cap. Together this answers my first and second questions.

Comment: Nice find! I hit this recently. 